# How to inject factory dependency into controller in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Scenario:-
I have a factory say testFactory. Now till now I was defining my controller as following:-

```
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope,testFactory)
{
  testFactory.Method1(){ //working fine}
}
```

But now before minimizing the file I defined the controller as:-

```
app.controller('testCtrl',['$scope','testFactory', function(a,testFactory)
{
   testFactory.Method1() {//throws undefined error}
}
```

I tried this:-

```
 app.controller('testCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope','testFactory', function(a,$rootScope,testFactory)
{
   testFactory.Method1() {//still thows error- unable to resolve dependency}
}
```

Now how should I include my factory in such case?

Comment: tip: I recommed that: controller and factories name should begin with captial letter, also, methods should not.

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev
my factory names starts with captial..but still throwing same erro

Comment: That tip doesn't fix your issue.  @Chetan, where does bracket "[" close

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problem with the factory declaration, try this

```
var TestCtrl= function($scope,TestFactory) {
  // ...
}
TestCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'TestFactory'];
app.controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl);
```